# Why is √ is not allowed as a objectName/stringName/functionName/NumberName?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coding a scientific calculator and I need some help:

```
function √(in){
    return Math.sqrt();
}
// throws an error
var √ = function(in){
    return Math.sqrt();
}
// also throws an error

var √ = "sqrt";
√randomSqNum = 100,
√random = {sqrt:4,cubert:8},
√sqNum = ["0","1","4","9","16","25"],
√null = null,
√undefined = undefined;
```

They all throw an error!
Please explain why they throw an error.
Also, Is there a way around this?

Comment: In what charset/encoding is your code? It should be Unicode (UTF-8), otherwise such var/func names are illegal

Comment: @hindmost is charset needed? because i don't have a charset

Comment: [The docs](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6) ...

Comment: Even if i put UTF-8 as a charset, it still does not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript follows [annex 31 of the unicode standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr31/) regarding identifier names.

I assume you are using [U+221A](https://codepoints.net/U+221A) as character. As you can see from the linked page, it can neither be used at the beginning of an identifier nor within it:

[image]

(likely because it is not even a letter).

Compare that to [`π`](https://codepoints.net/U+03C0), which is a letter and which can be used in an identifier name.

> Also, Is there a way around this?

No. However, you can always try to find letters that [look similar](http://shapecatcher.com/).

Comment: Really helpful, Thanks for taking your time to write this answer.

Answer (score 5):

In Javascript, variable names must begin with a letter, `_` or `$`. More information here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: If so, then explain why I could set a function/object/string/number named π without any errors?

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6

Comment: @JosephGoh π is a letter

Comment: Exactly what they said. π is a greek letter, and in this particular language is treated as a valid variable/function start letter, while the square root symbol isn't a letter in any language.

Comment: Just updated my question* @MHardwick

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use it directly as a name, but you can use it as key.

```
var f={}
f["√"] = Math.sqrt
alert(f["√"](5))
```

In such way you can define `+-*/` and many other funcions.

```
f["+"] = function(a){
  return a.reduce(function(p,v){
    return p+v
  },0)
}
```

And when you have a parsed statement tree in form `{o:fn,a:[s1,...,sn]}` where fn is function name and s1,...,sn are subtrees or values, then you can simply get the result:

```
function calc(st){
  return (typeof st == 'object')?f[st.o].apply(null,st.a.map(calc)):st
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!